# How to update dataframe column which contains array of structs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Schema of dataframe

```
  root
    |-- parentColumn: array
    |    |-- element: struct
    |    |    |-- colA: string
    |    |    |-- colB: string
    |    |    |-- colTimestamp: string
```

value inside dataframe look like this

```
"parentColumn": [
        {
            "colA": "TestA",
            "colB": "TestB",
            "colTimestamp": "2020-08-17T03:28:44.986000"
        },
        {
            "colA": "TestA",
            "colB": "TestB",
            "colTimestamp": "2020-08-17T03:28:44.986000"
        }
    ]
```

`df.withColumn("parentColumn", ?)`

Here I want to format all `colTimestamp` inside the array to UTC format, I saw many examples of updating values inside array but I'm not able to find a way to Update dict inside an array.

Comment: can you share a sample of how your actual df looks like? the sample code you've provided generates 3 distinct columns.

Comment: Hi @samkart, have updated the schema of dataframe and how data looks inside dataframe. We are reading json from file and creating dataframe so was not sure how replicate the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on spark 3.1+, you can use the `transform` function with [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark-sql-column-withfield) within a lambda function.

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('parent_col_new', 
               func.transform('parent_col', 
                              lambda x: x.withField('col_ts', 
                                                    func.to_timestamp(x.col_ts, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                                                    )
                              )
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |id |parent_col                                                                             |parent_col_new                                                           |
# +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |1  |[{test, testB, 2020-08-17T03:28:44.986000}, {UNREAD, USER, 2020-08-17T03:28:44.986000}]|[{test, testB, 2020-08-17 03:28:44}, {UNREAD, USER, 2020-08-17 03:28:44}]|
# +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# root
#  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
#  |-- parent_col: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- col_a: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- col_b: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- col_ts: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- parent_col_new: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- col_a: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- col_b: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- col_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

If `withField` and/or `transform` isn't available in your spark version, you can use `expr` and recreate the struct. It'll result in the same output.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('parent_col_new',
               func.expr('''
                         transform(parent_col, 
                                   x -> struct(x.col_a as col_a, 
                                               x.col_b as col_b, 
                                               to_timestamp(x.col_ts, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") as col_ts
                                               )
                                   )
                         ''')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Hi @samkart, In first example if we want to update other two parameter also how can we do it? for example if I want trim other two column how can it be done?

Comment: @Yadav - you can chain `withField` just like `withColumn`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `transform` function to apply a function to each element of the array. Then, since you don't have lots of fields, you can recreate the struct like this:

```scala
df.withColumn("parentColumn", transform('parentColumn, x => struct(
    x.getField("colA") as "colA",
    x.getField("colB") as "colB",
    to_utc_timestamp(x.getField("colTimestamp") , "GMT+2") as "colTimestamp"
)))
```

Comment: I'm new to spark, can you explain why there is open single quote before parentColumn.

Comment: It simply means column `parentColumn`. You can use this notation like you use `col("parentColumn")` or `$"parentColumn"`.